# nginx hhvm bad gateway

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm, php

I do have an issue with Nginx 1.6.2(compiled) and HHVM 3.4.2.
Everything is installed 'fine' when I run `hhvm info.php` it returns 'HipHop'.
But when I visit the website I get an 502 bad gateway, so HHVM runs fine, there must be an issue with nginx and/or php5-fpm.

```
netstat -an | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

hhvm.conf

```
location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
fastcgi_keep_conn on;
fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

site1.conf

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    include /etc/nginx/hhvm.conf;
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied

    root /opt/sites/www/site1;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

I'm totally stuck in here for few days now..

Comment: Did you check your logs?

Comment: `there must be an issue with nginx and/or php5-fpm` - If you are using hhvm, you shouldn't be using php-fpm. What are the contents of `/etc/hhvm/server.ini`, `/var/log/hhvm/error.log` and `/var/log/nginx/error.log` (or equivalent files)?

Comment: Nginx error log:
`2014/12/22 14:40:55 [error] 17340#0: *48 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 188.207.78.49, server:example.com, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:8000", host: "example.com"`

hhvm/server.ini: http://pastebin.com/Wiug2Fv5
HHVM error log is empty

Comment: The port in the question does not match the port in the error message.

Comment: That's something I'm trying to figure out. Currently one of the issues is that hhvm start init does not work. 502 error is caused because hhvm is not started. Although when hhvm fails, php5-fpm should kick in, but that's not happening.

Comment: Error messages don't lie, nginx is communicating with port 8000 - and there is nothing listening on that port. That means the relevant config isn't in the question; just looking for "8000" in your nginx config files will say what is. `hhvm start init does not work` + `when hhvm fails, php5-fpm should kick in` er, wat?